# How to show the current user's post and the all posts comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have many users, how to list only the posts of one and also show all the comments of other users?

post model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

comment model

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
```

user model

```
 has_many :posts
 has_many :comments
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :posts do
     resources :comments
 end
```

in controllers

```
def index
    @post =  User.posts.all
    @comment = User.comments.all
end
```

in views index.html.erb

```
<%@post.each do |post|%>
    <%=post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %> 
<%end%>

<%@comment.each do |comment|%>
    <%=comment.content %>
<%end%>
```

How can I show posts and comments from only a current user?

Comment: In order to access the posts for a specific user, you must instantiate that user, like `User.first.posts`, otherwise you're applying posts to the user model and Rails thinks is a method of it.

Comment: i am not geeting

Comment: @SebastianPalma  is right that you must instantiate that `User`. Please see my answer below. Hope that it will help you.

Comment: it show same ans all user post and comment ,i wnt to show  post and comment belongs to user

Comment: @adarsh we're here to help you. But your question is very unclear (hence the downvotes I guess). Therefore, please take your time to clarify your question. Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so you are now edited your questions with not a question. You are not now understand what is going on with your code. So, correct me if I'm wrong, is what you want is to show users and under users show their post and under post show the comments of that post? I am now taking an effort to understand you! But if still unclear, I think I will stay silent.

Comment: please help my english was not good

Comment: i think you got my question

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer with what I understand.

Comment: @araratan help me please

Comment: @araratan help me i edit my question

Comment: @adarsh constantly asking for help can be quite frustrating for the people who are already trying to help you.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma,@Stefan,@araratan thanks a lot for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to help you, let's first clarify your question, okay? do you want to show only the posts created user, want to show the post to the owner of the post only, and all comments, that? Or do you want to list all posts, and within the post, the comments? If not, can you cite an example?
Take the example that Araratan gave, what is not fit with what you want?
You can try something like this:

your users_controller.rb

```
 def index
      @users = User.all
    end
```

your posts_controller.rb

```
def index
   @posts= Post.all
end
```

your comments_controller.rb

```
 def index
      @comments = Comment.all
  end
```

in your view of post.
you can put this.

```
<% current_user.posts.each |post| %>
    #post fields like
    # <%= post.title %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        #comments fields like 
        # <%= comment.description %>
        #do you wanna show the author of comment?
    <% end %>
    #or, do you wanna show the author of post?
<% end %>
#from what I understand you want to show both, that?
```

you can use Araratan answer, but instead of listing all users and all posts of all users, you can put the current user. If you already implemented the part of the login.
I'll take the example and adapt

**Option #1**

Your User Model `have_many :posts` and Post `has_many :comments` so you can do it like this in your controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

And call each post by user and comments by post:

index.html.erb

```
  <% current_user.posts.each do |post|%>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**Option #2**
For using `includes`:

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:posts, :comments)
end
```

in your views:

**Views #1**

```
#but I think that's not what you want

  <% current_user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
  <% end %>

  <% current_user.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>
```

**Views #2:**

```
#I think this is what you want


  <% current_user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Will your userA be the current user?

Comment: like that i want to show userA all posts and comments for userA only

Comment: Can you try what I put in and say if it's more or less it?

Comment: Please stop shortening the terms, like pls, my English is not very good.

Comment: you got me my quesion

Comment: What was removed?

Comment: I'll edit your question so it's easy for everyone to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165670/discussion-between-adarsh-and-elis-bresciani).

Answer (score 6):

**Option #1**

Your User Model `have_many :posts` and Post `has_many :comments` so you can do it like this in your controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

And call each post by user and comments by post:

index.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% user.posts.each do |post|%>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Option #2**
For using `includes`:

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:posts, :comments)
end
```

in your views:

**Views #1**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
  <% end %>

  <% user.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Views #2:**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Views #3**
I am assuming that you have `first_name` field in your `User` Model.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.first_name %> 

  <% user.posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.post_name %>
    <%= post.post_description %>

    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= comment.content %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You could add a mention to `includes` to avoid creating additional queries.

Comment: it show all user post and comment ,i wnt to show  post and comment belongs to user

Comment: @adarsh, second option using includes can do what you want.

Comment: i use @users = User.includes(:posts, :comments) this it show all user data.i wnt to show only belongs to user post and comment data

Comment: Okay, @adarsh, I created `views #2`. I think in all the options or codes I have answer a while ago, you can construct what you what to get. I seems that you need to take a basic study on `ruby-on-rails`. But I hope that I have help you with the latest edit.

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to achieve. Your are not relating in your question above. You are not clear.